# Geocoder getFromLocationName() returns just 1 result

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding, reverse-geocoding, geocoder

Android Geocoder always returns just 1 possible address

```
val addressesList = Geocoder(this.context).getFromLocationName("Toledo", 5)
```

Expected : I want to get 5 possible addresses, which has Toledo in their names (
there are 
Toledo, USA; 
Toledo, Spain;
Toledo, Columbia, etc.)

Actual : Always get 1 address.

Answer (score 4):

The Geocoding API is not meant to be used for ambiguous queries such as "Toledo". It can be expected that the API won't necessarily return all possible matching results.

I suggest using [Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete) instead to get multiple results for broad inputs. Google's [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/best-practices) states:

> In general, use the Geocoding API when geocoding complete addresses
>   (for example, “48 Pirrama Rd, Pyrmont, NSW, Australia”). Use the
>   Places API Place Autocomplete service when geocoding ambiguous
>   (incomplete) addresses.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Right, but for Place Autocomplete API key is required, and for the Geocoding API is not.